# How can I find out which file was changed a few minutes ago?

Tags: command-line, find, ls

I want to transport a configuration from one user to another one. But I don't know in which file the program in question stores its configuration.

In order to find out where the configuration is stored, I want to change one setting of them and then look for any file which has changed in the last few minutes.

I know about `find . -mmin -10  -ls` but there are quite a few in the output and **I would like the result ordered by last change time**. Unfortunately the date is somewhere in the middle of the `ls` output of that command.

Comment: read the find man page  for the `-printf` directive -- that lets you format the output exactly how you want it, including the file's mtime in seconds for easy sorting.

Comment: So `find . -mmin -3 -ls -printf %C+ | sort` would be the right thing to list the files which have changed in the last tree minutes (from the directory where the command is issued). The last changed files go to the bottom then. How would one exclude the information after the change-timestamp at the very beginning to just before the blanc before the paths of the files found (i.e. take string positions 0 to 20 and everything from 103 on)? How can I pipe such an extraction before I further pipe the result to `sort`?

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at a few examples of using `find`:

1. with the `-ls` directive:

   ```
   $ find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -ls
   15533117     60 -rw-r--r--   1 root     wheel       60616 Jan  2 09:46 /var/log/daily.out
   15955192     12 -rw-r-----   1 root     admin        8638 Jan  2 10:00 /var/log/system.log
   15870477    132 -rw-r-----   1 root     admin      117797 Jan  2 09:45 /var/log/wifi.log
   1081546  32088 -rw-r--r--   1 root     admin    31966363 Jan  2 09:46 /var/log/install.log
   ```

   Clearly very hard to sort.
2. using `-ls` *and* `-printf`

   ```
   $ find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -ls -printf '%T+'
   15533117     60 -rw-r--r--   1 root     wheel       60616 Jan  2 09:46 /var/log/daily.out
   2020-01-02+09:46:36.1361086600 15955192     12 -rw-r-----   1 root     admin        8710 Jan  2 10:06 /var/log/system.log
   2020-01-02+10:06:54.3077120650 15870477    132 -rw-r-----   1 root     admin      117797 Jan  2 09:45 /var/log/wifi.log
   2020-01-02+09:45:28.8952892010  1081546  32088 -rw-r--r--   1 root     admin    31966363 Jan  2 09:46 /var/log/install.log
   2020-01-02+09:46:04.0508866900
   ```

   Quite a mess with the timestamp printed on the *next* line with no
   newline.
3. using `-printf` only: we'll print the mtime, a tab, the pathname and a newline:

   ```
   $ find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -printf '%T+\t%p\n'
   2020-01-02+09:46:36.1361086600  /var/log/daily.out
   2020-01-02+10:06:54.3077120650  /var/log/system.log
   2020-01-02+09:45:28.8952892010  /var/log/wifi.log
   2020-01-02+09:46:04.0508866900  /var/log/install.log
   ```

   OK, straightforward. Let's sort it so the newest is on top

   ```
   $ find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -r
   2020-01-02+10:06:54.3077120650  /var/log/system.log
   2020-01-02+09:46:36.1361086600  /var/log/daily.out
   2020-01-02+09:46:04.0508866900  /var/log/install.log
   2020-01-02+09:45:28.8952892010  /var/log/wifi.log
   ```

   And then just print the pathname

   ```
   $ find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -mmin -30 -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -r | cut -f 2-
   /var/log/system.log
   /var/log/daily.out
   /var/log/install.log
   /var/log/wifi.log
   ```

Comment: +1 .-) I made my own shellscript `newfiles` using the same method as you describe here.